# How can I change AirPod volume with one hand? (while riding a bike)

Tags: audio, airpods

I need to adjust the volume of the AirPods while riding my bike.  This could be because the audio is now in "loud commercial mode" or because I need to pay closer attention to my surroundings.

- What is the quickest, most immediate, way of adjusting volume on the AirPods, aside from removing one from the ear?  (and pausing the audio)

Answer (score 2):

You can pause the audio by modifying the settings of the AirPods so that when you double tap on an AirPod, instead of activating Siri, it plays/pauses instead. This can be done in Settings > Bluetooth > AirPods. As for volume, I don't think there's a way. I personally have my iPhone mounted to my bike (with a Quad Lock case), and I control the volume with the iPhone volume buttons.

Comment: I'll have to look at that case; I just don't want another thing to think about when I lock my bike in the city (remove seat/lights/and now this thing)

Comment: You can pick up a pretty cheap quad lock kit from eBay. Also another thing I do is just adjust the volume from my phone while it's in my pocket, through my pants.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the volume with one hand is to use Siri.

But triggering Siri may cause you to miss something of the audio that is playing (especially when it's an audio book).

I've configured my left AirPod to play/pause, and the right one to trigger Siri. So then:

1. Double-tap left AirPod to pause.
2. Double-tap right AirPod to trigger Siri.
3. Say "increase volume", "decrease volume", "volume to max", or something like that to change the volume.
4. Double-tap left AirPod to play.

By default, both AirPods trigger Siri. You'll need to change the double-tap action for the left AirPod. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207009.

*Note: In the initial AirPod firmware, it was impossible to assign different actions to each AirPod.*